# How would you model this shoe in blender

Tags: modeling

Im a beginner in blender, from a graphic design background. I learn quickly, and if it makes sense, i learn best from concepts and examples, more so than text book style information. I understand the guy who did is may be a pro (and am 100% sure that this is a 3d render and not an actual shoe) . Ive learned in 3d modeling, that visualizing it is 80% of the battle, as far as having a plan on HOW to model something. The skill and program knowledge comes next. The sole of the shoe is mostly what seems impossible to do in blender. Modeling shoes is what i got into 3d for, so if anyone knows where to find a SOLID shoe modeling tutorial, please refer them this way! Thank you all! I want to know how to make the sole SPECIFIALLY

[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome. This site is more geared towards specific question and focused help, as it stands this is too broad. If you can rephrase your post to focus on the specific part you are having difficulties please edit it, so we can reopen. Maybe show what you have tried, or a few screenshots of where it failed

Comment: i dont know where to start and thats why im asking

Comment: Since you are new and a beginner standard advice is start small, watch some beginner tutorials, work your way up

Comment: You could do some tutorials specifically on the subdivision modifier. I would also advise to start small. For example making a basic computer mouse should be a nice first excercise. And after that you might still need many many tries to get the right mesh for the sole. For best modeling (and learning) results i would advise from personal experience to completely remake the object as often as you can (from the very start) instead of trying to repair an approach that wasn't optimal. Here a small guide to the skills i think you would need for your project: https://imgur.com/a/4B2PdWh

Comment: Robert Roth youre the greatest!

Comment: @RobertRoth youre the greatest!

Comment: @KarlRico :) Extra tip: A useful approach for making a nice base mesh (nicer than in my picture) would be to do some rough sculpting of the sole (or the whole shoe) in blender (in "sculpt mode") and then do "manual retopology" (many many good videos... maybe search "sculpt retopology") when you have something close to the shape you want (to get a nice base mesh before the subdivision modifier).

Comment: While it will take a bit longer to do the sculpt and the retopology, having it in blender gives you more control over the exact shape you will achieve. Basically the sculpt is a 3d reference for you to make mesh that is closer to what you want. And to make the sculpt you might use some 2d reference pictures/drawings as background.

Comment: @RobertRoth thanks bro! Any way you can share the .blend file from the picture? It would help LOTS!

Comment: @KarlRico I strongly recommend doing retopology for achieving a nice base mesh so you have more vertexes to control the shape more accurately. I added a small manual retopology sample. (BTW: For retopology the "snap to face" magnet setting is extremely helpful.)  [The sole model](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6350/)

Comment: @RobertRoth thanks man! I will do that! Is there some sort of way i can show appreciation?

Comment: @KarlRico You're welcome! :)